# How to create appointment exception from recurring series?

Tags: exchangewebservices

How to create appointment exception from recurring series using the EWS API?  I checked all documentation, and could not find that information.

```
Appointment occurrence = Appointment.BindToOccurrence(service, new ItemId(sRecurringMasterId), 3)
```

It is for already existed exception, but how to create one and connect to the recurrent master?

Answer (score 1):

> It is for already existed exception, but how to create one and connect to the recurrent master?

You don't create exceptions directly, all you need to do is bind to the Occurrence then modify the occurrence see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-update-a-recurring-series-by-using-ews. If you modify the date or any other properties when you update the occurrence it will create an exception for you. Basically the way it work is this modifies the Master instance in some case the exception will be a hidden attachment on the underlying master item in others case (depending on what properties you change) it will just modify the recurrence blob https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/how-to-read-and-parse-a-recurrence-pattern.

You can't link another appointment you create as an exception because of the above reason its just a standalone appointment (or store item).

Comment: But if I don't have occurrence? I have DailyPattern with until date. Number of occurrences is 0 in recurring master. to Bind Occurence, I need occurrence index.

Comment: You need to do an expansion query with a start and end date https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-appointments-and-meetings-by-using-ews-in-exchange that will expand the pattern on the master into virtual occurrences then modify the occurrence you want to change which will create an exception to the pattern.